# Google sheets to calendar with invite and edit events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Scenario: I want several users to add titles dates, descriptions, etc to a calendar for discussion events they are holding via google meet. This should be all handled by a trigger on a google sheet. If an event is edited within the google sheet then the event in the calendar should also be edited.
I found some code, slightly edited it and it somewhat works.

What Works: events are created and guests are invited and therefore the google meet is created (as long as 1 guest is invited). editing an event also works

What does not work: if the time for 2 events clashes, for example, event one runs from 14:00 - 15:00 and event two runs from 14:30 - 15:30 then only event two is added to the calendar.

Can anyone help with how to enable adding overlapping events?

```
function create_calendar() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var index = 2;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (;index <= lastRow; index++){
  
  var taskTitle = sheet.getRange(index, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
  var taskDesc = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
  var location = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
  var startDate = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  var guests = sheet.getRange(index, 6, 1, 1).getValue();
  
  var type = sheet.getRange(index, 7, 1, 1).getValue();
  var onCalendar = sheet.getRange(index, 8, 1, 1).getValue();
  var status = sheet.getRange(index, 9, 1, 1).getValue();
  
  var sendInvites = true;
  if (onCalendar == 'Yes' && startDate && endDate && status != 'Done')
  {
    var events =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById("INSERT CALENDAR ID HERE").getEvents(startDate, endDate);
    delete_events(events);
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("INSERT CALENDAR ID HERE").createEvent(taskTitle, 
                                                                                      startDate, 
                                                                                      endDate,
                                                                                      {description: taskDesc, 
                                                                                        location: location, 
                                                                                        guests: guests, 
                                                                                        sendInvites: sendInvites}
                                                                                      );

  }
    
}// End of for Loop
  
}// End of CalendarTest Function
```

Comment: Where is the function `ev.deleteEvent()` defined?

Comment: Thinking about it further and I don't think that I will need that delete function as any events cancelled will just be edited to say they are cancelled events. 

I will rephrase my original question to just ask how to enable it to add overlapping events.

Comment: I think this line is a problem for creating overlapping events `delete_events(events);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Events');
const startRow=1;
let vA=sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1,9).getValues();
vA.forEach(function(r,i){
  var taskTitle = r[0];
  var taskDesc =r[1]; 
  var location =r[2];
  var startDate =r[3];
  var endDate =r[4];
  var guests =r[5];
  var type =r[6];
  var onCalendar =r[7];
  var status =r[8];
  var sendInvites = true;
  if (onCalendar=='Yes' && startDate && endDate && status != 'Done')
  {
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById("INSERT CALENDAR ID HERE").createEvent(taskTitle, startDate, endDate,{description:taskDesc,location:location,guests:guests,sendInvites:sendInvites});
  }
});
```

---

#### Reference:

- [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))

Comment: Thank you Cooper, I am now getting an exception

Exception: The parameters (String,(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

However i know this is because the code is expecting something that is not provided within the sheet. This gives me something to investigate and work on, thank you

Comment: Your missing stateDate [createEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object))